# Let, $D_{8}$ act on itself via conjugation, find the character of this representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, representation-theory

Where, $D_{8} = <r,s: r^{4} = e,s^{2} = e, sr^{-1} = rs >.$ Let, $g \in D_{8}$, then define $\psi_{g}:\mathbb{C}D_{8} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}D_{8}$ where  $\psi(x) = gxg^{-1}$, and we can extend the above to a linear map. Am I correct in assuming that to obtain the character of this representation that I would have to construct an $8$ by $8$ matrix where each element of $D_{8}$ is encoded into a vector; for example, we can say that $r = (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), r^2 = (0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0) $, and so on, and then construct $5$ ( number of conjugacy classes) 8 by 8 matrices that represent our action and take the trace of those $5$ matrices, is this how one would solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an easier way, I think: each $\psi_g$ will permute the elements $D_8$, so this can be thought of as a permutation representation. That is, every $\psi_g$ can be represented as a permutation matrix. Then to take the trace, just count the number of fixed elements. This doesn't require writing down the matrix. (I am not super familiar with representation theory, though, so if someone could confirm I am not mistaken, that would be appreciated!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, since I have thought about it a bit more and am pretty sure I was not lying.

Note that for each $g,x,y\in D_8$, we have $\psi_g(x) = \psi_g(y)\Leftrightarrow x=y$, so each $\psi_g$ permutes the elements of $D_8$. This is equivalent to permuting the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{C}D_8$ (which correspond to the elements of $D_8$). Thus each $\psi_g$ can be represented by a permutation matrix with respect to this basis. This means that each row and each column of $\psi_g$ contains exactly one entry of 1, with all other entries being 0. The trace of such a matrix is the number of 1s on the diagonal; in this case, that is the number of basis vectors fixed by $\psi_g$, or, equivalently, the number of $x\in D_8$ such that $\psi_g(x)=x$.

So we can write down the character of this representation without worrying about working explicitly with $8\times 8$ matrices: instead, count how many elements $x\in D_8$ are fixed by each $\psi_g$.

Perhaps this question might also be relevant: [Permutation representation of the conjugation action of a finite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122696/permutation-representation-of-the-conjugation-action-of-a-finite-group?rq=1)